# bash script aborts after the push failed using the curl command

Tags: shell, curl, bitbucket

I am using the curl command to create a pull request in bitbucket. The script aborts after the push failed through curl.

```
if curl -v -w httpcode=%{http_code} -u \ 
    ${BITBUCKET_USERID}:${BITBUCKET_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: \ 
    application/json" -X POST -d "$json_data" \
    $url/rest/api/1.0/projects/$project/repos/$repo/pull-requests >> $log_file 2>&1 ; then

    PR_URL=$(grep -o "https://bitbucket.com/projects/[a-zA-Z_-]*/repos/[a-zA-Z_-]*/pull-requests/[0-9]*" $log_file | tail -1)

else
    error "curl command failed with exit code:$curl_exit_code and http code:$httpcode"
fi
```

The curl command is working fine when there is no push failure.

```
Please find the error log:
-> Pushing branch {repo}:auto-test-0606 ...(ok)
-> Creating Pull Request for {repo} (auto-test-0606 -> master)...
PR_URL: https://bitbucket.ciena.com/projects/{project}/repos/{project}/pull-requests/{pr_id}
-> Pushing branch {repo1}:auto-test-0606 ...
Error: Push failed with error message: Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
-bash-4.2$
```

There are some more repos that needs to be created but the script is aborting unexpectedly. Please help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance